# fontsquirrel font

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-face, embedded-fonts

I have a webfont that uses css `@face-face`, is there a problems with this use of font that is not a "standard" font like Arial or Tahoma? is this method is 100% cross browser support ?

Yhe code looks like that:

```
font-family: 'myfont_OERegular';
src: url('myfont-webfont.eot');
src: local('myfont_OE'), local('myfont1'), url('myfont_-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('meodedpashut_myfont-webfont.svg#webfont4Amd3DHq') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never a "100%" cross-browser method for anything.  Furthermore, loading fonts for a website like this is even more unreliable.  This generally isn't an issue, as long as you are happy with 95-97% of your browsers looking "correct".  But there are undoubtedly exceptions.

If you must have a specific font for certain content (such as headings), then the best you can do is load an image.  But then, you must take precautions for those that don't load images, are blind, or are search engines.

Finally, make sure you have a license if you are distributing a font.

Comment: is right, there is never a 100% cross-browser method for anything, but I've used FontSquirrel's @font-face generator and the files and code it exports and I always have very consistent results, even in IE6!

Answer (score 0):

the support for font face is really good
look: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/

and i am using also fontsquirrel and kernest and it works every where, where i tested it (modenr browsers, not too old browsers like ie 5.5, ...)